# Duplicate classes androix.appcompat:appcompat

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

I recently delete facebook login from my app and now I got these errors. I tried to clean my project, invalidate caches and restart, add multidex, make up to date all dependencies but the error is still present.

```
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources found in modules appcompat-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0) and appcompat-resources-1.4.1-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawableCompat found in modules appcompat-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0) and appcompat-resources-1.4.1-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawableCompat$1 found in modules appcompat-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0) and appcompat-resources-1.4.1-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawableCompat$AnimatableTransition found in modules appcompat-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0) and appcompat-resources-1.4.1-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawableCompat$AnimatedStateListState found in modules appcompat-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0) and appcompat-resources-1.4.1-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawableCompat$AnimatedVectorDrawableTransition found in modules appcompat-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0) and appcompat-resources-1.4.1-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawableCompat$AnimationDrawableTransition found in modules appcompat-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0) and appcompat-resources-1.4.1-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawableCompat$FrameInterpolator found in modules appcompat-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0) and appcompat-resources-1.4.1-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawableCompat$Transition found in modules appcompat-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0) and appcompat-resources-1.4.1-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer found in modules appcompat-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0) and appcompat-resources-1.4.1-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer$1 found in modules appcompat-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0) and appcompat-resources-1.4.1-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer$BlockInvalidateCallback found in modules appcompat-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0) and appcompat-resources-1.4.1-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer$DrawableContainerState found in modules appcompat-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0) and appcompat-resources-1.4.1-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper found in modules appcompat-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0) and appcompat-resources-1.4.1-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable found in modules appcompat-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0) and appcompat-resources-1.4.1-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState found in modules appcompat-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0) and appcompat-resources-1.4.1-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.widget.DrawableUtils found in modules appcompat-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0) and appcompat-resources-1.4.1-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourcesWrapper found in modules appcompat-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0) and appcompat-resources-1.4.1-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.widget.TintContextWrapper found in modules appcompat-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0) and appcompat-resources-1.4.1-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.widget.TintInfo found in modules appcompat-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0) and appcompat-resources-1.4.1-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.widget.TintResources found in modules appcompat-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0) and appcompat-resources-1.4.1-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1)
Duplicate class androidx.appcompat.widget.VectorEnabledTintResources found in modules appcompat-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0) and appcompat-resources-1.4.1-runtime (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I found that my lottie files compose depencies were on version 4.0.0 and it uses wrong appcompat dependencies. I just upgraded to 5.0.3 and it works now.

```
//Lottie
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie-compose:5.0.3'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
It worked for me after a couple of hours trying to fixing it.